# What does ... mean in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am an elementary Python programmer and have been using this module called "Pybaseball" to analyze sabermetrics data. When using this module, I came across a problem when trying to retrieve information from the program. The program reads a CSV file from any baseball stats site and outputs it onto a program for ease of use but the problem is that some of the information is not shown and is instead all replaced with a "...". An example of this is shown:

```
from pybaseball import batting_stats_range

data = batting_stats_range('2017-05-01', '2017-05-08')

print(data.head())
```

I should be getting:

https://github.com/jldbc/pybaseball#batting-stats-hitting-stats-for-players-within-seasons-or-during-a-specified-time-period

But the information is cutoff from 'TM' all the way to 'CS' and is replaced with a ... on my code. Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) states, `head()` is meant for "quickly testing if your object has the right type of data in it." So, it is expected that some data may not show because it is collapsed.

If you need to analyze the data with more detail you can access specific columns with other methods.
For example, using `iloc()`. You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc), but essentially you can "ask" for a slice of those columns and then apply a new slice to get only `nrows`.

Another example would be `loc()`, docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc). The main difference being that `loc()` uses labels (column names) to filter data instead of numerical order of columns. You can filter a subset of specific columns and then get a sample of rows from that.

So, to answer your question "..." is pandas's way of collapsing data in order to get a prettier view of the results.